# How can a Python program load and read specific lines from a file?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a huge file of numbers in binary format, and only certain parts of it needs to be parsed into an array. I looked into `numpy.fromfile` and `open`, but they don't have the option to read from location A to location B in the file. Can this be done?

Comment: Sure it can be done. Read and ignore lines until you reach location A, then read and parse lines until location B.

Comment: Files are streams. Let data stream by that doesn't interest you, handle what does.

Comment: That seems like inefficient if he has "a huge file of numbers"...

Comment: @ErikAllik: without any more detail on what location A means exactly, we don't know if seeking is sufficient. That generally only works if you are dealing with fixed-sized records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with "huge files", I would **not** simply read-ignore everything up until the point where you actually need the data.

Instead: file objects in Python have a `.seek()` method which you can use to jump right where you need to start parsing the data efficiently bypassing everything before.

```
with open('huge_file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(1024 * 1024 * 1024)  # skip 1GB
    ...
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: And how do you know where to skip *to*? With files with lines of irregular length there is no way of knowing what to skip.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case, but he didn't specify either.

Comment: Which is why I kept my feedback to a comment and voted to close instead. The question is too vague to answer, really.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the precise location of the data you are interested in, you could just use the `seek(<n bytes>)` method on the file object as [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Just call it once (with the given offset) before you start to read.